# VideoView setVideoUri No Content Provider

Tags: java, android, uri, mp4, android-videoview

I am developing an Android app that needs to play an .mp4 video from my local server.

I have this code:

```
    mPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_preview);
    mPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mPreview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.100:7676/getVideoByFileName.php?name=C%3A%2FSpinShot%2FResults%2FSpinShot-201701311359177714.mp4"));
    mPreview.setOnPreparedListener(createOnPreparedListener());

    private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener createOnPreparedListener() {
        return new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    };
}
```

And every time it gets executed, I get this error:

```
   D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
                                                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.1.100:7676/getVideoByFileName.php?name=C%3A%2FSpinShot%2FResults%2FSpinShot-201701311359177714.mp4
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1141)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:991)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:914)
                                                                             at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1121)
                                                                             at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:371)
                                                                             at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:71)
                                                                             at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:652)
                                                                             at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:712)
                                                                             at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:209)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1014)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2510)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7403)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

No video plays in the VideoView. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the entire code of how you are setting up the media player?

Comment: @OBX i edited the code snippet.

Comment: Are you on the same network? I mean when retrieving the video from Android?

Comment: alos crosscheck that video does exists on the url that you are using

Comment: @VivekMishra I have checked it. Same URL plays the video on my pc browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Firewall affects their connection. Turned it off and it works just fine.